# JQuery Window.Resize switching CSS Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I've almost completed a retro-fitting job in order to make a HTML 4 website *Responsive*. I don't want to use device-testing approaches to loading content/CSS/JQuery - instead, I'm trying to be true to the *Responsive idea*: one website that responds to different window sizes.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

1. At window size 798px or greater, the website's sub-menu displays as
   it always has, no problem.
2. At window size 797px or less, the CSS for the sub-menu is *replaced*
   with that of the jquery.flexnav.js plugin.

In both instances the CSS is different, and they need to remain different for historical reasons.

There's no problem with switching styles, since the plugin handles this. But, when the window is resized from 797px to 810+, for example - elements are still bound to flexnav.js.

At 798px or greater, the UL/LI elements need to be cleared of all connection to flexnav.js, and at 797px or less, flexnav.js kicks in.

**The problem:**

I can't seem to get flexnav.js to clear, and so the sub-menu remains collapsible at window 798px or greater. If I resize the window below 798px, and then resize back to 798px or greater, flexnav.js still affects, incidentally, I understand the reasoning why this is.

**What I've tried:**

To make it so that styles/behaviour changes on window resize, as opposed to needing a Reload.

I adapted this to work with my IDs and Class names: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rzdGJ/1/

```
(function($) {
    var $window = $(window),
        $ul = $('ul#myone');

    $window.resize(function resize() {
        if ($window.width() < 514) {
            //return $html.addClass('mobile');
            return $( "ul#myone" ).addClass( "flexnav" );
        }

        //$html.removeClass('mobile');
        $( "ul" ).removeClass( "flexnav" )
    }).trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

**My samples code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="http://urly.be/flexnav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (max-width: 798px)">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>




<ul id="myone" class="flexnav">
  <li>1
    <ul>
        <li>1a
            <ul>
                <li>1b</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
   if ( $(window).width() <= 798) {     

       document.write('<scr'+'ipt src="http://urly.be/js/jquery.flexnav.js" type="text/javascript"></sc'+'ript>');
       document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($){$(".flexnav").flexNav();});</sc'+'ript>');
    }



    </script>
<!-- COMMENTED OUT - ORIGINAL PLUGIN JQUERY <script src="http://www.agilenation.co.uk/custom/temp/flexnav-master/js/jquery.flexnav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $(".flexnav").flexNav();

        });
    </script>-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggling the class for flexnav will not help after it has been initialized. It adds a lot of inline styles and binds events for the drop downs etc. The only reasonable way to clear flexnav would be to remove the menu element from the DOM and append a new element on the resize event.

Have you tried:

- setting the data-breakpoint="798" on the parent ul
- adapting the old menu styles to override the flexnav styles using the `.lg-screen` selector
- initializing flexnav only once on domready

Another option might be to have two menu instances, one with the flexnav bindings and one without and just toggle the menu display property on resize, or with a media query:

```
.old-menu{
    display:none;
}

@media screen and (min-width:798px){
    .old-menu{
        display:inherit;
    }
    .flexnav{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: **POINT 1:** There are no issues with adapting the CSS at data-breakpoint - the main issue is with the binded events, as you say, resulting in the old menu acting like an accordion at 798+. So I hoped I'd be able to removeClass - which, as above JSFiddle, works on it's own.

**POINT 2:** I'll look into .lg-selector.

**POINT 3:** I'll look into this.

I have full FTP access to source & PHP, so two menus might be the way forward. But, flexnav would still be in charge. "Remove element from DOM"... again I'll look into this - but removeClass seems like the ideal way?

Comment: Removing the class will just effect the styles not any bound events. As long as the old menu appears and behaves appropriately after having flexnav initiated on it and the class removed, go with that.

Comment: I see! So, two menu version with class="old-menu", class="flexnav" - I was hoping I could avoid mangling the PHP, but seems like the only sure way (at least as a temporary measure).